# docker pull failed. manifest invalid: manifest invalid - artifactory

Tags: docker, artifactory

docker 1.9.1 pull on centos7 is failing when pulling from private V2 registry.

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 1.9.1, build 78ee77d/1.9.1

$ docker pull web-docker.bin-repo.hostname.com/web-dev:latest
Trying to pull repository web-docker.bin-repo.hostname.com/web-dev ... 

failed
manifest invalid: manifest invalid
```

The same command works fine on osx with docker 1.10.3.  Can anyone tell me why this isn't working and how to troubleshoot further?

**update**:  here is the manifest it's trying to pull.  It can pull v1 manifests, but fails on v2 manifests like the one below.

```
{
   "schemaVersion": 2,
   "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json",
   "config": {
      "mediaType": "application/octet-stream",
      "size": 7503,
      "digest": "sha256:58672cb2c8c6d44c1271a5ca38e60a4ab29fb60050bc76995ce662c126509036"
   },
   "layers": [
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
         "size": 32,
         "digest": "sha256:a3ed95caeb02ffe68cdd9fd84406680ae93d633cb16422d00e8a7c22955b46d4"
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
         "size": 72038766,
         "digest": "sha256:35d9d5d11536c0c6843ecd106dc710b5c54b8198aa28710e73dba2cbe555847f"
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
         "size": 19361671,
         "digest": "sha256:f7de7971859186e93100b41fbba5513771737ba65f57c62404130646bd41b96b"
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
         "size": 108814795,
         "digest": "sha256:0041a80e34f1271571619554f6833c06e0ef75d39f152f5fe44ba75bf7e25ae2"
      },
      {
         "mediaType": "application/vnd.docker.image.rootfs.diff.tar.gzip",
         "size": 157895786,
         "digest": "sha256:ec3cfa9c22f7e6497a0eacf85c86bf8eb5fdec35d096298f9efb43827a393472"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For this issue what I observed is that whenever you push the same image artifact for the second time with same SHA, we will observe this issue.

To Solve this, I would recommend giving permission to override/delete the mainifest file in artifactory.

This will definitely solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Problem resolved itself after upgrading to a new version of Docker. (Docker version 1.10.3, build 20f81dd)  The standard yum repo lags behind in versions, so add the docker repo and get the latest version of docker:

```
 sudo yum update
```

Add the yum repo:

```
 sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/docker.repo <<-'EOF'
 [dockerrepo]
 name=Docker Repository
 baseurl=https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/$releasever/
 enabled=1
 gpgcheck=1
 gpgkey=https://yum.dockerproject.org/gpg
 EOF
```

Install the docker-engine:

```
 sudo yum install docker-engine
```

Start the daemon:

```
 sudo service docker start
```

Add the insecure-registry flag (if the priv registry does not have a cert)

```
 sudo vi /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
```

> ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon --insecure-registry web-docker.bin-repo.hostname.com -H fd://

Reload the daemon:

```
 sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Pull from the private registry:

```
  sudo docker pull web-docker.bin-repo.hostname.com/web-dev:latest
  latest: Pulling from web-dev

  a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete
```